# Smallest ring into which a collection of other rings can be embedded

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose that I have a collection $R_1,\ldots,R_n$ of unital rings of characteristic two. I want to construct the smallest ring into which each $R_i$ can be embedded via unital ring monomorphisms.

Many of the rings I am dealing with are very similar to each other; only their multiplication is different. Is there a name for such a construction?

Comment: Even up to isomorphism smallest rings are not unique

Comment: your rings are $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebras — isn’t then the tensor product of all of them the answer you’re seeking?